# What is Photoproduction

Tags: particle-physics, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

I wonder what photoproduction means in the context of pion decay and vector meson dominance? What is the reaction formula, Feynman diagram for such a photoproduction thing? Is it simply a reaction where the final state is a bunch of photons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photoproduction is a process where something is produced by the interaction of a high energy photon. Something like
$$ \gamma + p \to p + \pi^0 \,. $$

Experimentally it is useful because the electromagnetic vertex is well understood, and photon taggers allow the selection of events with incident photons with well know energy and momentum.